# Magento 1.9: cannot re-enable cache

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

I've just finished upgrading to CE 1.9.3.7, and I want to re-enable the cache.

I select all cache components, and on the right choose Enable from Actions, then Submit, and the page refreshes with all caches disabled still.

[image]

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the value from 0 to 1 in core_cache_option table.